# .presentation modifier is not working for alert ? Getting this error that VStack has no member 'presentation'

Tags: swiftui

I am making Tic Tac Toe using swiftUI and in order to give a alert who wins or there is a tie and with tapping on 'Ok' alert will dismiss

Anyone up there please help me to resolve this ??

[This is the actual error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Hy6z.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. Your situation could be frustrating but the same as us with your question... please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: I have added the actual screenshot of error on the given link 'This is the actual error'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.alert` instead of `.presentation`

```
  struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAlert = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showingAlert = true
        }) {
            Text("Show Alert")
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
            Alert(title: Text("Important message"), message: Text("Wear sunscreen"), dismissButton: .default(Text("Got it!")))
        }
    }
}
```